# Set GUC parameter or use PGOPTIONS environment variable with PgBouncer

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer, pg-trgm

Can I make PgBouncer preserve the PGOPTIONS environment variable in transaction pooling to configure GUC parameters? Or is there another way to configure these parameters in PgBouncer so that it applies to all connections?

I specifically need to set some [pg_trgm parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.42.7)

Comment: You could set the parameter in `postgresql.conf` or with `ALTER DATABASE` or `ALTER ROLE`. I think those are your only options.

Comment: You can also set guc variables on a session level, with SET, (or transaction level with SET LOCAL), and I'm wondering if there's a way to make PgBouncer set a GUC parameter for every new connection to the database server.

Comment: After looking at your profile, you're likely aware of these options, and mean that they're not possible with PgBouncer. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Yes, I think there is no way to do that in pgBouncer. But I don't know every nook and cranny of pgBouncer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `connect_query` option in database definitions, like

```
mydb = host=myhost dbname=mydb connect_query='set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold=0.5'
```

`connect_query` can be any SQL statement.